# How to get $ E_{X,X'}[e^{\lambda(X-X')}]=E_{X,X',\epsilon}[e^{\lambda\epsilon(X-X')}] \,(*) $?

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics

For a Rademacher variable $P(\epsilon=+1)=P(\epsilon=-1)=1/2$ and a zero-mean r.v. such $X\in [a,b]$, let $X'$ be an independent copy of $X$. Then we know that $X-X'=_d \epsilon(X-X')$. But why do we have the following symmetrization trick?
$$
E_{X,X'}[e^{\lambda(X-X')}]=E_{X,X',\epsilon}[e^{\lambda\epsilon(X-X')}] \,(*)
$$

My questions are

(1) Waht does notation $E_{X,X'}(\cdot)$ mean? Does it mean $E_{X}(E_{X'}(\cdot))$?

(2) It seems that (*) tells us
$$
E_{\epsilon}[e^{\lambda\epsilon(X-X')}]=e^{\lambda(X-X')}? 
$$
But
$$
E_{\epsilon}[e^{\lambda\epsilon(X-X')}]=\frac{1}{2}e^{\lambda(X-X')}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda(X-X')}
$$
They are not equal... So how to get (*)?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the first part more carefully : the interpretation of the expectation is likely correct , but the condition mentioned in $(2)$ is much stronger than the condition mentioned in $(1)$. It is true that $E_{X,X'}[E_{\epsilon}[e^{\lambda \epsilon(X-X')}]] = E_{X,X',\epsilon}[e^{\lambda(X-X')}]$, from $(1)$. So all you know about the two quantities that you write about in $(2)$ is that their *expectations* are equal. There is no reason for them to be equal, and indeed they aren't i.e. $(2)$ is false.

Comment: I am confused why (*) is true? Can you prove it?

Comment: If you look at my last comment and the last expression you wrote, taking the $E_{X,X'}$ over that expression and comparing it to $E_{X,X'}[e^{\lambda(X-X')}]$ will show you that it's enough to prove that $E_{X,X'}[-e^{-\lambda(X-X')}] = E_{X,X'}[e^{\lambda(X-X')}]$. Can you see why this is true?

Comment: I am sorry but am I the only one who sees four weird line breaks in the title in the question list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X,X'$ have the same distribution and $\epsilon$ is independent of both than:

$E_{\epsilon,X,X'}[e^{a\epsilon(X-X')}]=\frac{1}{2}( E_{X,X'}[e^{a(X-X')}]+E_{X,X'}[e^{a(X'-X)}])$

( you are off by a sign in your last equation )

Than now observe that since $X,X'$ have the same distribution, by symmetry for every $f$:

$E[f(X-X')]=E[f(X'-X)]$

If you are not convinced, clearly if $X$ and $X'$ span the same values, than so do the differences $X-X'$ and $X'-X$. Therefore they have the same distribution:

$X-X'$ ~ $X'-X$

and their common density is even. Alternatively rewrite the expectations in term of the densities and change the naming of the variables.

This implies that the two addends are equal and the result that you want to prove.